# Calculating Big O complexity of Recursive Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, code-complexity

Somehow, I find that it is much harder to derive Big O complexities for recursive algorithms compared to iterative algorithms. Do provide some insight about how I should go about solving these 2 questions.

*assume that submethod has linear complexity

```
def myMethod(n)
    if (n>0)
    submethod(n)
    myMethod(n/2) 
    end
end 

def myMethod(k,n)
    if(n>0)
    submethod(k)
    myMethod(k,n/2) 
    end 
end
```

Comment: Did you try to convert these to iterative algorithms? They're both tail-recursive and easy to make iterative. For example, the first is `while n > 0 { submethod(n); n /= 2;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, the recurrence will be:

```
    T(n) = n + T(n/2)

    T(n/2) = n/2 + T(n/4)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    T(2) = 2 + T(1)

    T(1) = 1 + T(0) // assuming 1/2 equals 0(integer division)

adding up we get:

    T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ..... 1 + T(0)

         = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 .....) + k // assuming k = T(0)

         = n*1/(1 - 1/2)  ( sum of geometric series a/(1-r) when n tends to infinity)

         = 2n + k
```

Therefore, **T(n) = O(n)**. Remember i have assumed n tends to infinity ,cause this is what we do in **Asymptotic analysis**.

For your second problem its easy to see that, we perform **k primitive operations everytime till n becomes 0**. This happens **log(n)** times. Therefore, **T(n) = O(k*log(n))**

Comment: Yes, I see thank you so much! I have a better understanding of it now

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is **count how many times a basic operation is executed**. This is true for analysing any kind of algorithm. In your case, we will count the number of times `submethod` is called.

You could break-down the running time of call `myMethod(n)` to be `1 + myMethod(n / 2)`. Which you can further break down to `1 + (1 + myMethod(n / 4))`. At some point you will reach the base case, in `log(n)`th step. That gives you an algorithm of `log(n)`.

The second one is no different, since `k` is constant all the time, it will again take `log(n)` time, **assuming `submethod` takes constant time** regardless of its input.

Comment: Hmm thank you for your input, but the answer for the first is ~O(n) and ~O(k logn)  if i recall correctly. That's where my confusion is because of how similar the 2 algorithms look yet different their answers are

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i assumed `submethod` was taking constant time regardless of the input...